# Cannot Convert from string to char

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a string that I am trying to replace the double quotes to a "space" so I tried:

```
NAME=t1["NAME"].ToString().Replace('"'," ")
```

but that doesn't seem to work I get the below error:

> cannot convert string to char
>
> the best overload method match for string.Replace(char, char) has some
>   invalid arguments.

Comment: `.Replace("\""," ")`

Comment: [Did you try looking at the documentation?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx)  Do you see an overload that takes a character for the first argument and a string as the second?  Pick an overload and format your argument properly.

Comment: Pretty simple solution.  The left side of the replace needs to match the right side.  Char to Char,  you have a mismatch of car and string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
NAME=t1["NAME"].ToString().Replace('"', ' ')
```

Both parameters should be `char`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @CodeMan `' '` != `''`